# How can I refresh viewModel livedata from another activity

Tags: java, android

I am developing android application and I want to refresh viewModel livedata from second activity. When I get back to first activity data is not refreshed.

FirstActivity:

```
 mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MenuViewModel.class);

mViewModel.getMenus().observe(this, menuResponse -> {
            if (menuResponse != null) {
                resMenus.addAll(menuResponse.getMenus());
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

MenuViewModel:

```
public class MenuViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<MenuResponse> restMenuData;
    private MenusRepository mRepository;

    public MainActivityViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        mRepository = MenusRepository.getInstance(application);
        restMenuData = mRepository.getMenus();
    }

    public LiveData<MenuResponse> getMenus() {
        return restMenuData;
    }
}
```

MenusRepository

```
 private MenusRepository(Context context) {
        apiRequest= RetrofitInstance.getInstance(context).getApiRequest();
    }

    public synchronized static MenusRepository getInstance(Context context) {
        if (projectRepository == null) {
            projectRepository = new MenusRepository(context);
        }
        return projectRepository;
    }

public MutableLiveData<MenuResponse> getMenus() {
        final MutableLiveData<MenuResponse> data = new MutableLiveData<>();
        apiRequest.getMenus().enqueue(new Callback<MenuResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<MenuResponse> call, @NonNull Response<MenuResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
                    data.setValue(response.body());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<MenuResponse> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                data.setValue(null);
            }
        });
        return data;
    }
```

SecondActivity:

```
MenuViewModel mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(Objects.requireNonNull(SecondActivity.this)).get(MenuViewModel.class);
        mViewModel.getMenus();
// This line not refresh menus
```

I except to refresh data from viewmodel, but it return old data.
How can I refresh viewmodel data in best practices?

Answer (score 3):

`MenusRepository.getMenus()` methods creates a new instance of `LiveData` for every call. This is not the correct way to go about it.

You should have only one instance of `LiveData` and different objects subscribe to it (activity, viewModel, etc).

What you could do is - create a singleton of `MenusRepository` (which I think you have already done). Create one instance of `MutableLiveData` only and use it to update the data.

```
class MenusRepository {
    private val liveData = MutableLiveData<MenuResponse>()

    fun getMenus() {
        // Your api call. Do not create a new instance of the livedata.
    }

    fun menus(): LiveData<MenuResponse> {
        return liveData
    }

    fun update(data: MenuResponse) {
        liveData.post(data)
    }
```

This code is in Kotlin, but it applies similarly to Java as well.

You can `update` method to post an update to liveData. When you update it, all the observers will receive the new data. Use `MenusRepository.menus()` to access LiveData in your ViewModel.

---

Update

Your `MenuRepository` class could be like this.

```
private final MutableLiveData<MenuResponse> liveData = new MutableData<>();
private MenusRepository(Context context) {
    apiRequest= RetrofitInstance.getInstance(context).getApiRequest();
}

public synchronized static MenusRepository getInstance(Context context) {
    if (projectRepository == null) {
        projectRepository = new MenusRepository(context);
    }
    return projectRepository;
}

public MutableLiveData<MenuResponse> loadMenus() {
    apiRequest.getMenus().enqueue(new Callback<MenuResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<MenuResponse> call, @NonNull Response<MenuResponse> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
                liveData.setValue(response.body());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<MenuResponse> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
            liveData.setValue(null);
        }
    });
}

public LiveData<MenuResponse> getMenus() {
    return liveData;
}

public void updateData(response: MenuResponse) {
    liveData.postValue(response);
}
```

- When you want to update the data manually (from another activity),
  use `menuRepository.update()` method. This will post the data to your LiveData which will update all its observers, ie. the ViewModel.
- Call `menuRepository.loadMenu()` when you want to get the data using API.
- Use `menuRepository.getMenus()` to get the LiveData and attach your observers.

Since `MenuRepository` is a singleton, there's only one instance of `LiveData`. When you will post an update to this instance of LiveData, all the observers will receive the new data.

Comment: I edit repository class, can you give me an example for this?

Comment: I am sorry. I am new in mvvm. Last question, I can not updateData from another activity. Where can I get response? And where I use viewModel? Can you show example viewmodel of this situation, and update from external? Thanx

Comment: @Benfactor why do you say that you can not update the data from another activity? You're not updating the ViewModel data but asking your repository to update the data. As mentioned in the snippet, call MenuRepository.getInstance().updateData(data) where data is the updated data. If you mean that you want to make an API call from another activity to update the data, use loadMenu() method.

Comment: To call updateData(data), I need some data to send?

Comment: Yes. That's basically your question that you want to update the data from your second activity. What do you want to update?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195659/discussion-between-benfactor-and-froyo).

Comment: Is it safe to have these static LiveDatas? All the examples I see have the LiveData members inside a ViewModel, but I don't see how to have my Repository update LiveData without having the LiveData inside the non-ViewModel Repository.

Comment: @MooingDuck there is no static variable LiveData in this example.

Comment: @Froyo, er, not static. But a LiveData outside of a ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MenuViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
private MutableLiveData<MenuResponse> restMenuData;
private MenusRepository mRepository;

public MainActivityViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    mRepository = MenusRepository.getInstance(application);
    restMenuData = mRepository.getMenus();
}

public LiveData<MenuResponse> getMenus() {
    restMenuData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    return restMenuData;
}
}
```

Change the View model code as above.
So that the live data is always cleared before returning to activity.

Comment: This makes it clear that this is a view model, rather than a repository.  I have many ViewModels that all should access the same repository, but I can't see how to set up a repository to be able to update the LiveData objects.